# Google script : how to just copy the last line corresponding to the criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to scripting, I'm trying for personal use to automate the copy of data according to a main sheet and I'm stuck on a trick.

I just adapted this script to copy data from one sheet to another, however when it runs the same data is copied in a loop in addition to the new ones. I just try to copy only the new rows when I run the script.

Thx for your help

```
function CopyDataGames() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
  var topsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copie");
  var topsheetLastRow = topsheet.getLastRow();

  let lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  
  let sortRange = sheet1.getSheetValues(2,2,lastRow,44);

  Logger.log(lastRow)
   Logger.log(typeof(sortRange))
 Logger.log(sortRange.length);


 let topCounter = 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++){
  let name = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
   console.log(i + " - " + name);
  // find the name

  if (name =="PoinPOin"){
    let rowValues = sheet1.getRange(i,1,1,44).getValues();
    topsheet.getRange(topsheetLastRow+topCounter,1,1,44).setValues(rowValues);
   topCounter++; }
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- About `however when it runs the same data is copied in a loop in addition to the new ones.`, I think that the reason for this issue is due to that your script doesn't confirm the existing values of "Copie" sheet. In order to achieve your goal, I think that it is required to confirm the values of "Copie" sheet.
- In your script, `getValues` and `setValues` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function CopyDataGames() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
  var topsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copie");

  // I modified below script.
  var srcValues = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dstObj = topsheet.getDataRange().getValues().reduce((o, r) => (o[r.join()] = r, o), {});
  var res = srcValues.filter(r => r[1] == "PoinPOin" && !dstObj[r.join()]);
  if (res.length == 0) return;
  topsheet.getRange(topsheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of the "Source" and "Copie" sheets are retrieved. And, the duplicated values are checked. And then, the new values are put into the "Copie" sheet.

#### Note:

- If you want to check only the last row of "Source" sheet, how about the following modified script?

  ```js
  function CopyDataGames() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
    var topsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copie");

    // I modified below script.
    var lastRowValue = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var dstObj = topsheet.getDataRange().getValues().reduce((o, r) => (o[r.join()] = r, o), {});
    if (lastRowValue[1] != "PoinPOin" || dstObj[lastRowValue.join()]) return;
    topsheet.appendRow(lastRowValue);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)